# Android build.gradle importing flavors from another file

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I have put the product Flavors into another file called `other.gradle` and it looks like this:

```
project.ext.myflavors =  {
 mock {
     applicationId "com.mysite.mock"
 }

}
```

and i am able to successfully access the closure in my `build.gradle` file like this:

```
myflavors()
```

but i get an error that mock method is not defined.

```
Error:Gradle DSL method not found: 'mock()'
```

Is there no way to just define code from another file and import the code itself into the build file ? Or how can i import the flavors from another file ?

Comment: I do not think this makes sense. `productFlavors` extension belong inside the `android` block. This is like removing a method from a class and posting it in another class and hoping it will still work the same.

Comment: yah your right. i just seen that issue now. But is there no way to have the flavors defined in a seperate file ?

Comment: Not unless you move the entire `android` block to a separate `build.gradle`. Why do you want to do this anyways?

Comment: i want to have two separate flavors depending on a boolean im gonna set in the gradle.properties.  So i'll check this boolean and load flavorGermany if true, else if false i'll load flavorUSA

Comment: thanks for the idea about moving the entire android block out. I might be able to live with that if you want to make an answer.  But if you know how to import just the flavor closure itself it could be less duplication for me.

Comment: Like I said, I really do not think you can. `android.productFlavors` is what you need to access, you can try storing it like that. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/build/#Configuration-options

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is perfectly fine to access `productFlavors` multiple times. So adding some or all flavors in a script included by your build script will work.

Create a Gradle script that contains the logic that decides which flavor(s) should be added:

```
if (someCondition()) {
    android {
        productFlavors {
            one {
                applicationId = 'com.example.oneapp'
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    android {
        productFlavors {
            two {
                applicationId = 'com.example.twoapp'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now include this script from your build script. Reusing the scripts is easy if you put it under (a subfolder of) the root project. For example:

```
apply from: rootProject.file('build-scripts/flavor-picker.gradle')
```

Note that your IDE may not notice changes to the flavor selection script or `gradle.properties`, so if you make changes to them you will probably have to manually reimport the Gradle files to see the correct set of available tasks.

Comment: Android Studio noticed it well.

Answer (score 10):

The build flavors could be defined in a separate file (`build_flavors.gradle`) like this:

```
android {
    productFlavors {
        flavorA {
            // ...
        }
        flavorB {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

and then imported into `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: './build_flavors.gradle'

android {
    // the rest of your android configuration
}
```